# Cloudformation: What's the best practice of chopping the configuration file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

**Description**

I'm developing a web application with AWS, in order to deploy my endpoints and lambda functions to my sandbox, I used cloudformation to help with managing the resources. However, as the project grows, I found there are too many repeated resources in my template.yaml file such as:

```
  CreateUserFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/function-user/
      Handler: app.create
      Environment:
        Variables:
           ...
      Policies:
        ...
      Events:
        xxxApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /users
            Method: post
```

Basically I created this kind of resource for each endpoint and the size of template.yaml is over 2000 lines. I think there should be some approach to chop the template file into pieces for easier maintenance.

**Approach I Tried**

1. I chopped the template file into pieces according to different endpoint
2. I wrote a scripts with following actions:

   - Merge endpoint resources into one and upload to S3 bucket
   - Compress each lambda function and upload the zip file
3. In each template file(such as UserResource.yaml with definition of User CRUD endpoint), I specified the CodeUri with the zip file in S3 bucket
4. In master template file, I used AWS::Include to import the merged resources file from S3 bucket

**Result**

The approach I tried works exactly fine. It can deploy the resources successfully like before and I end up with a template.yaml with less than 300 lines and a bunch of chopped yaml files.

**Question**

Even my solution works, I don't think this is the best practice, because every time I want to deploy after change, I have to run the script to upload resources. I want to know the best practice to manage the resources.

*I'm new to AWS and a non-native speaker, please bear with me if I didn't make myself clear or made some silly mistake, thank you!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out its not a good practice to create and then manage third party scripts to stitch together your CFN templates.

You have to remember that CFN is not a programming language as you may be used to. A repetition is a natural part of it. Having said that, you can consider the following solutions native to CFN:

- [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) - a common way to re-use and parametrize common resources
- split your template into logically separated templates, e.g. networking stack, API stack and DB stack. Then you re-use them through [Exporting stack output values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html)
- There are also [CFN macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) and [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that can server as substitute for lack of loops in CFN.

If this is still not enough, then maybe CFN is simply not suited for your usecase. Then you have to look at much more powerful IoC tools such as Terraform or CDK (CDK is from AWS and "complies" to CFN).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try them out!